# How to resolve mapreduce runtime error "Initialization of all the collectors failed"

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

my hadoop version is2.7.7

I write a mapreduce program to get which recorder is the lastest.
The record like this

> a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277482,108.92466,34.27657
> a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277488,108.92527,34.27658
> a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277506,108.9276,34.27659
> a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277476,108.92399,34.27655
> a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277515,108.9291,34.2766
> a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277512,108.92859,34.2766
> a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277497,108.92627,34.27659
> a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277509,108.92809,34.27659
> a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277500,108.92667,34.27659
> a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277491,108.92561,34.27658
> a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277479,108.92434,34.27657

dirver_id,order_id,unix_time,longitude，latitude

i want to get the last recoder(order by unix_tim) of each order

i meet this problem

> 20/09/26 16:45:32 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master/10.251.254.88:8032 20/09/26 16:45:33 WARN
> mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not
> performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application
> with ToolRunner to remedy this. 20/09/26 16:45:33 INFO
> input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1 20/09/26
> 16:46:43 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Exception in createBlockOutputStream
> java.io.IOException: Got error, status message , ack with firstBadLink
> as 10.251.253.236:50010   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.DataTransferProtoUtil.checkBlockOpStatus(DataTransferProtoUtil.java:140)
>
> at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1497)
>
> at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1400)
> at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:554)
> 20/09/26 16:46:43 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Abandoning
> BP-1227587342-10.251.254.88-1600940262422:blk_1073742778_1954 20/09/26
> 16:46:43 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Excluding datanode
> DatanodeInfoWithStorage[10.251.253.236:50010,DS-21c974dd-296a-489d-8512-0e13947176b2,DISK]
> 20/09/26 16:46:43 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Slow waitForAckedSeqno took
> 70082ms (threshold=30000ms) 20/09/26 16:46:43 INFO
> mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:21 20/09/26 16:46:43 INFO
> mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job:
> job_1600941960831_0027 20/09/26 16:46:44 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl:
> Submitted application application_1600941960831_0027 20/09/26 16:46:44
> INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job:
> http://master:8088/proxy/application_1600941960831_0027/ 20/09/26
> 16:46:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1600941960831_0027
> 20/09/26 16:47:38 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1600941960831_0027
> running in uber mode : false 20/09/26 16:47:38 INFO mapreduce.Job:
> map 0% reduce 0% 20/09/26 16:47:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id :
> attempt_1600941960831_0027_m_000005_0, Status : FAILED Error:
> java.io.IOException: Initialization of all the collectors failed.
> Error in last collector was :class cn.mikyan.OrdersDriver     at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.createSortingCollector(MapTask.java:414)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.access$100(MapTask.java:81)     at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.(MapTask.java:698)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:770)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)   at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)  at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
> org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158) Caused
> by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class cn.mikyan.OrdersDriver    at
> java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)   at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getOutputKeyComparator(JobConf.java:887)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.init(MapTask.java:1004)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.createSortingCollector(MapTask.java:402)
> ... 9 more
>
> Container killed by the ApplicationMaster. Container killed on
> request. Exit code is 143 Container exited with a non-zero exit code
> 143

and my code is this, sorry for it is very long

```java
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator;

import cn.mikyan.writable.Orders;

public class OrderGrouping extends WritableComparator{
    
        public OrderGrouping() {
            super(Orders.class,true);
        }
        @Override
        public int compare(WritableComparable a, WritableComparable b) {
            Orders acc1 = (Orders)a;
            Orders acc2 = (Orders)b;
            System.out.println("3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333");
            return acc1.getOrderid().compareTo(acc2.getOrderid());
            //以订单ID  来决定分组依据
        }

}
```

```java
package cn.mikyan.mapper;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.RawComparator;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Partitioner;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;


import cn.mikyan.writable.Orders;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class LogCleanMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Object , NullWritable> {

    private String[] fields;

    Orders orders=new Orders();
    private String driverid;    //司机的id
    private String orderid; //订单id
    private String time; //unix时间戳 unixtime
    private String xp; //经度 
    private String yp; //维度
    private  Orders order;

    @Override
    protected void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        fields = value.toString().split(",");
        if (fields == null || fields.length != 5) { // 有异常数据
            return;
        }
        driverid = fields[0];
        orderid = fields[1];
        

        time = fields[2];
        xp = fields[3];
        yp = fields[4];

        System.out.println("3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333");
        order=new Orders(driverid,orderid,time,xp,yp);
        System.out.println(order.toString());
        context.write(order,NullWritable.get());

    }
    

 
}
```

```java
package cn.mikyan.reduce;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

import cn.mikyan.writable.Orders;

public class OrderReducer extends Reducer<Object, Text, Object,NullWritable> {

    private String orderId;

   protected void reduce(Orders key, Iterable<NullWritable> values, Context context)
           throws IOException, InterruptedException {

       
       for(NullWritable v2:values){
           context.write(key,NullWritable.get());
           break;//默认是升序
       }
       
   }
}
```

```java
package cn.mikyan.writable;

import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;

public class Orders implements WritableComparable<Orders> {

    private String driverid; // driver_id
    private String orderid; // order_id
    private String time; // unix_time
    private String xp; // longitude
    private String yp; // latitude


    
    public Orders() {

    }
    public Orders(String driverid, String orderid, String time, String xp, String yp) {
        this.driverid = driverid;
        this.orderid = orderid;
        this.time = time;
        this.xp = xp;
        this.yp = yp;
    }


    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {// ***
        out.writeUTF(driverid); // 序列化
        out.writeUTF(orderid);
        out.writeUTF(time);
        out.writeUTF(xp);
        out.writeUTF(yp);

    }


    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {// ***
        driverid = in.readUTF(); // 序列化
        orderid = in.readUTF();
        time = in.readUTF();
        xp = in.readUTF();
        yp = in.readUTF();


    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Orders o) { // *****
        System.out.println("44444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444");
        int tem = orderid.compareTo(o.orderid);
        if (tem == 0) { // 如果订单ID相同的话，就 进行cost的比较
            //time.compareTo(o.time)>0
            //(cost > o.getCost()
            if (time.compareTo(o.time)>0){
                return -1;// -1：降序 1：升序
            }
            return 1;
        }
        return tem;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return driverid + "," + orderid + "," + time + "," + xp + "," + yp;
    }

 

    public String getDriverid() {
        return driverid;
    }

    public void setDriverid(String driverid) {
        this.driverid = driverid;
    }

    public String getOrderid() {
        return orderid;
    }

    public void setOrderid(String orderid) {
        this.orderid = orderid;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getXp() {
        return xp;
    }

    public void setXp(String xp) {
        this.xp = xp;
    }

    public String getYp() {
        return yp;
    }

    public void setYp(String yp) {
        this.yp = yp;
    }
}
```

```java
package cn.mikyan;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

import cn.mikyan.Group.OrderGrouping;
import cn.mikyan.mapper.LogCleanMapper;
import cn.mikyan.reduce.OrderReducer;

public class OrdersDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("mapred.job.queuename", "order");
        
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(OrdersDriver.class);
        job.setJobName("Sencondary Sort");
        job.setMapperClass(LogCleanMapper.class);  
        job.setCombinerClass(OrderReducer.class);
        
        job.setReducerClass(OrderReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(OrdersDriver.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setGroupingComparatorClass(OrderGrouping.class);
        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        
        Path outfile = new Path(otherArgs[1]);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
        
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,outfile);
        //Path outfile=new Path("/MaxID/out");
        FileSystem fs = outfile.getFileSystem(conf);
        if(fs.exists(outfile)){
            fs.delete(outfile,true);
        }
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1);
    }

}
```

Hoping your answer and thanks ver much.